# onPause event getting called after app update in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-lifecycle

I'm facing a weird behavior in my Android application.

I have an `Activity` in which I'm showing camera preview and recording video. But whenever Play Store update any application in background, after updating application my activity's `onPause()` is automatically getting called.

I'm stopping my recording on `onPause()` method. This weird behavior is creating a problem for me.

```
  @Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.e(TAG, "OnPause");
    try {
        stopStreaming();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    unbindService(serviceConnection);
    AppController.getInstance().getEventBus().unregister(this);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Can Play Store execute `onPause()` event of my `Activity`?

### Update

I found that this happened just after PlayStore install the updated application. I think on PACKAGE_INSTALL broadcast. And my activity flash for a second.

Comment: Maybe its related to the notification that shows up when it finish to update an app? but it should not affect your app, as any other notification...

Comment: Yes that's true. But I found that this only happen just after PlayStore install the updated application. I think on PACKAGE_INSTALL broadcast.

Comment: I've noticed this behaviour too.  But I haven't verified why so not sure if it's PACKAGE_INSTALL broadcast.  I have noticed something interesting though... YouTube app continues to play videos when in multi-screen mode even though this must mean that onPause is being called for it when other app becomes active. However, YouTube app pauses video when app is installed in background. Perhaps it's listening for PACKAGE_INSTALL broadcast (or related) and stops playback at this time?  I wonder why though.

Comment: Here I am, struggling with the same issue two years later... Any update on it?